# Pandas: create new column based on above row in the newly created column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have [a two-column numerical dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOWVm.png), and I'm trying to add a 3rd column.

```
    Row    col1    col2
 
    0      8       8      
    1      8       4   
    2      6       2   
    3      3       7   
    4      6       4   
    5      2       6
```

Where in the first row,
`col3 = max(col1 - col2,0)`
and on the rest of the rows,
`col3 = max(col1 - col2 + col3_of_the_row_above, 0)`

The [resulting dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwroG.png) should look like this:

```
    Row    col1    col2    col3
 
    0      8       8       0   
    1      8       4       4
    2      6       2       8
    3      3       7       4
    4      6       4       6
    5      2       6       2
```

Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: Is there a specific issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: @AMC OP asks: "I'm trying to add a 3rd column" ... "Is there an efficient way to do this?". What more would you like the OP to say?

Answer (score 2):

To create a new column you can just do this:

```
 df['col3'] = 0 # all the rows will be filled with zeros
```

col3 will be added in you dataframe.

Because the calculation method of your first row is different of the others, you'll need to this manually.

```
df['col3'][0] = max(df['col1'][0] - df['col2'][0], 0)
```

The calculation method of the other rows is the same, so you can do this with a for iteration.

```
 for row in range(1, len(df)):
        df['col3'][row] = max(df['col1'][row] - df['col2'][row] + df['col3'][row - 1], 0)
```

P.S: You can do this using list comprehension too, maybe it's too early, but I'll put the code too so you can study the code.

```
df['col3'] = 0 # all the rows will be filled with zeros
df['col3'] = [max(df['col1'][row] - df['col2'][row] + df['col3'][row - 1], 0) if row > 0 else max(df['col1'][row] - df['col2'][row], 0) for row in range(len(df))]
```

This is a more pythonic way to this, but it can be a little confusing
at first sight.

Comment: Hello, @AdrianMole, I edited the aswer. Do you think it looks good now?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# Calculate value for first row clip lower value to zero
s = (df.iloc[0, df.columns.get_loc('col1')] - df.iloc[0, df.columns.get_loc('col2')]).clip(0,)

# Calculate difference for each row after first
df['col3'] = (df.iloc[1:, df.columns.get_loc('col1')] - df.iloc[1:, df.columns.get_loc('col2')])

# Fill 'col3' with first value then cumsum differences
df['col3'] = df['col3'].fillna(s).cumsum()

df
```

Output:

```
     col1  col2  col3
Row                  
0       8     8   0.0
1       8     4   4.0
2       6     2   8.0
3       3     7   4.0
4       6     4   6.0
5       2     6   2.0
```